# Percona Toolkit "pt-table-sync" ... a MySQL synchronization tool ... didn't

Tags: mysql

I issued the following command:

```
pt-table-sync --verbose --databases medics --execute h=10.11.22.77,u=root,p=secret h=127.0.0.1,u=root,p=secret
```

... *(as well as a similar command specifying `D=/t=` on the DSN to process only one table)* ...

and, after a few minutes, got a promising-looking output like this:

```
# DELETE REPLACE INSERT UPDATE ALGORITHM START    END      EXIT DATABASE.TABLE
#     25       0   3380    437 Nibble    14:50:49 15:09:05 2    medics.address_book
```

... but when I looked at the table in the target database, it had not changed at all!  Re-running the command produced identical output, apparently because the command was seeing the same *(unchanged)* situation each time, and it never actually synchronized anything.

Why not?

(This is using the Percora Toolkit distro that is currently available on Ubuntu LTS.  Furthermore, *both* systems are running the same version of Ubuntu LTS and the same (current) version of MySQL.  I can see that the software thinks it knows what it's doing because *(e.g.)* it correctly recognized when one table didn't exist.)

(The *source* database is a replication slave.  The *target* is an unrelated *(identical)* development-only database which does not participate in any replication relationships. I do not see how the source's "replication *slave"* status could be relevant, but I wanted to disclose this fact. I would prefer not to run against the master as the source, and have not yet tried to do so.)

This SO post, [Percona's pt-table-sync: how to run on more than one table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802326/perconas-pt-table-sync-how-to-run-on-more-than-one-table/22570610#22570610), shows the user issuing a very-similar command *(to the second one I tried, not shown in this post ...)*, and the OP said that "this will successfully update table1."  Uh huh, as I would expect.  But I tried to do the selfsame thing and it didn't.  So, why isn't it working for *me?*  `:-)`

No error messages – no clues.  No obvious indications of anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

*(Where's the "d'Oh!" icon around here?)*

I found the problem:  this is a **false alarm.**  I was replicating against a slave which had fallen out-of-sync with its master, then comparing results against the master.

Percona apparently *did* synchronize correctly against the slave to which it was pointed, but of course this data did not match the master.